# Shiny App, Warning: Error in max: invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to produce a shiny app with 3 drop-downs, which can select a variable. The app runs, in terms of I get a dashboard, but I do not get the desired output. When selecting a particular variable, there are no changes to the table or tree output.

I am modifying a pre-existing code which works for two variables, by adding a new variable "Year". I get the following message

"Listening 
Warning: Error in max: invalid 'type' (list) of argument
  96: collapsibleTreeSummary
  95: func [O:\DIVISIONAL DRIVES\Research/2019]
  82: origRenderFunc
  81: output$plot
   1: runApp"

Below is part of my server code

---

```
observeEvent(input$reset_input,{
p <- NULL
output$plot <- renderCollapsibleTree({
  dat <- data.1()
  p <- collapsibleTreeSummary(
    dat, hierarchy = c("Sector  Area","Sub-sector  Area"," Organisation"), root = "Framework", attribute = "Number of attempts", inputId = "node", zoomable = FALSE,
    fillFun = colorspace::heat_hcl, fontSize = 11)
  p
})

session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message = "node")
})
```

---

Or will it be something else?

Comment: It seems to be a problem in your server code. Specifically, where you defined `output$plot` . Can you edit your post with the corresponding code?

Comment: I have made an edit

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)